# Extending D for four-derivatives

Tags: pattern-matching, vector-calculus, physics

I'm currently trying to consistently define rules for extending D[] to four-derivatives. As 'backend' I'm using the package TRACER (http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/2987/), which can perform contractions with metric tensors, Dirac algebra, etc. Derivatives, however, are not implemented in this package. The rules here are independent of TRACER, but I adapted it's syntax, so

- `S[k, {σ}]` is the four-vector $k_\sigma$
- `S[{μ}, {ν}]` is the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$

The basic assumption is that $\frac{\partial}{\partial k^\sigma}k^\rho=g^{\sigma\rho}$.

So far, I have

```
D[S[notk_Symbol, idx_List], S[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] := 
    0 /; FreeQ[notk, k];
D[S[k_Symbol, index_List], S[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] := 
   S[index, derividx];
D[S[param1__]^n_Integer, S[deriv_, derividx_]] := 
   n S[param1]^(n - 1) D[S[param1], S[deriv, derividx]]
```

For multiplication and addition, I have

```
D[S[param1__] + S[param2__], S[deriv_, derividx_]] := 
    D[S[param1], S[deriv, derividx]] + D[S[param2], S[deriv, derividx]];
D[S[param1__] * S[param2__], S[deriv_, derividx_]] := 
    D[S[param1], 
      S[deriv, derividx]]*S[param2] + S[param1] * D[S[param2],
      S[deriv, derividx]]];
```

And for scalar products:

```
D[S[k1_Symbol, k2_Symbol], S[k_, derividx_List]] := 
    D[S[k1, {dummy}],
      S[k, derividx]] S[k2, {dummy}] + S[k1, {dummy}] D[S[k2, {dummy}],
      S[k, derividx]];
```

These, however, do not deliver the correct results (the result is in fact 0) when trying to derive a product or sum with more than two terms. `//Trace` confirms that Mathematica does not know what to do.

Does anyone have a pointer?

Comment: The result is 0 because you use `D`, you should define a new function rather than modify `D`.

Comment: Great suggestion! I just realized Mathematica will leave unknown expressions unevaluated, instead of setting them equal to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can define a function called `partialD` for your purpose.

General definitions:

```
(* For addition*)    
a : partialD[_Plus, ___] := Thread[Unevaluated[a], Plus, 1]
(* For multiplication *)
partialD[a_Times, x___] := Plus @@ (MapAt[partialD[#, x] &, a, #] & /@ Range[Length[a]])
(* For power *)
partialD[a_ ^b_, x___] := b a^(b - 1) partialD[a, x]
```

Specific to your problem:

```
partialD[S[notk_Symbol, idx_List], S[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] := 0 /; FreeQ[notk, k]
partialD[S[k_Symbol, idx_List], S[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] := S[idx, derividx]
(* for scalar product *)
partialD[S[k1_Symbol, k2_Symbol], S[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] := Module[{i}, 
    partialD[S[k1, {i}], S[k, derividx]] S[k2, {i}] + S[k1, {i}] partialD[S[k2, {i}], S[k, derividx]] /. 
    S[a_Symbol, j_List] (S[j_List, l_List] | S[l_List, j_List]) :> S[a, l]]
```

Defining the format of your `S` function for a nice-looking output

```
Format[S[k_Symbol, {i_}]] := DisplayForm@SubscriptBox[k, i]
Format[S[{i_}, {j_}]] := DisplayForm@SubscriptBox[g, RowBox[{i, j}]]
```

Test:

```
partialD[S[k, k] + S[p, k] + S[k, {b}], S[k, {a}]]
(* its FullForm is: Plus[Times[2,S[k,List[a]]],S[p,List[a]],S[List[b],List[a]]] *)
```

Comment: I added the definitions `PartialD[a_, S[var_, idx_List]] := 0 /; NumericQ[a]` and
`PartialD[S[idx1_List, idx2_List], S[var_, derividx_]] := 0;` to define the derivative for numbers as well as for the metric tensor. Works quite nicely now :)