# Mathematica: Partial derivative with respect to tensors

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, tensors, differentials

Anyone know how to do the partial derivative of a tensor in d dimensions on Mathematica ?

I want to implement something which will calculate directly like that :

[image]

Comment: It works the same as with scalars, each element is derived separately.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please provide an example of a tensor so that a concrete discussion can ensue.

Comment: Hi @Syed, I edited my post with more details of what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to utilize `FeynCalc` --- see [this link](https://feyncalc.github.io/)

```
<< FeynCalc`;
```

---

$\frac{\partial p^{\mu}}{\partial p^{\nu}}$

```
FourDivergence[FVD[p, μ], FVD[p, ν]]
```

> `g^(μν)`

---

$\frac{\partial p^{\mu}}{\partial p^{\mu}}$

```
FourDivergence[FVD[p, μ], FVD[p, μ]]
```

> `D`

---

$\frac{\partial p^{-2}}{\partial p^{\nu}}$

```
FourDivergence[1/SPD[p, p], FVD[p, ν]]
```

> `-((2 p^ν)/p^4)`

Another approach would be to define in mathematica something, say `partD`, and implement the rules of differentiation. If you like this latter approach, ping a comment and I will try to update.

Edit after the comment: for the latter approach see the very useful information contained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20406/extending-d-for-four-derivatives). It is an excellent response by the user @unstable, so please upvoting it!

Also, I have not used this code in a while so please make sure to run extensive tests. Below I am giving the basics and some basic results. You might need to add a couple of lines for yourself.

We start by some basic rules

1. Basic rules

1.1: Addition

```
a : pD[_Plus, ___] := Thread[Unevaluated[a], Plus, 1]
```

1.2: Multiplication

```
pD[a_Times, x___] := 
 Plus @@ (MapAt[pD[#, x] &, a, #] & /@ Range[Length[a]])
```

1.3 Powers

```
pD[a_^b_, x___] := b a^(b - 1) pD[a, x]
```

2. Definitions for covariant type terms -- - indices down --- $\partial_a x_b$

`pD[fvd[notk_Symbol, idx_List], fvd[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  0 /; FreeQ[notk, k] pD[fvd[k_Symbol, idx_List], fvd[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  fvd[idx, derividx]`

3. Definitions for contravariant type terms -- - indices up --- $\partial^a x^b$

`pD[fvu[notk_Symbol, idx_List], fvu[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  0 /; FreeQ[notk, k] pD[fvu[k_Symbol, idx_List], fvu[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  fvu[idx, derividx]`

4. Definitions for mixed quantities --- $\partial_a x^b$ and $\partial^a x_b$

`pD[fvd[notk_Symbol, idx_List], fvu[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  0 /; FreeQ[notk, k] pD[fvd[k_Symbol, idx_List], fvu[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  fvmix[idx, derividx]`

and for the latter form

`pD[fvu[notk_Symbol, idx_List], fvd[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  0 /; FreeQ[notk, k] pD[fvu[k_Symbol, idx_List], fvd[k_Symbol, derividx_List]] :=  fvmix[idx, derividx]`

5. Display format - I had a Euclidean metric so it is written as a Kronecker-$\delta$

`Format[fvd[k_Symbol, {i_}]] := DisplayForm@SubscriptBox[k, i] Format[fvu[k_Symbol, {i_}]] := DisplayForm@SuperscriptBox[k, i] Format[fvd[{i_}, {j_}]] :=  DisplayForm@SubscriptBox[δ, RowBox[{i, j}]] Format[fvu[{i_}, {j_}]] :=  DisplayForm@SuperscriptBox[δ, RowBox[{i, j}]] Format[fvmix[{i_}, {j_}]] :=  DisplayForm@SubsuperscriptBox[δ, RowBox[{j}], RowBox[{i}]]`

Ok, so now how we can code stuff:

First, displaying the metric:

```
fvd[{a}, {b}]
```

> `δ_{ab}`

and with indices up

```
fvu[{a}, {b}]
```

> `δ^{ab}`

and with up-down

```
fvmix[{a}, {b}]
```

> `δ^{a}_{b}`

So, you get the idea. Recall that 4-vectors are symbol and list, i.e

```
fvd[x, {a}]
```

> `x_{a}`

A couple of minimal examples:

1. $\partial_a x_b$

`pD[fvd[x, {b}], fvd[x, {a}]]`

> `δ_{ba}`

Let's do a sum as well to make sure it works

```
pD[fvd[x, {b}] + fvd[x, {c}], fvd[x, {a}]]
```

> `δ_{ba} + δ_{ca}`

We also do a product

```
pD[fvd[x, {b}] fvd[x, {c}], fvd[x, {a}]]
```

> `x_c δ_{ba} + x_b δ_{ca}`

Something a bit more complicated

```
pD[(fvd[x, {a}] fvd[x, {a}])/fvd[x, {b}], fvd[x, {a}]]
```

[image: vectors]

Comment: Thank youuu, and Yes please I would love to know about this latter approach. Thanks.

Comment: @borisgbeasor please see the revised reply :-)